# localStorage is not shared across tabs in the private mode in mobile Safari

Tags: javascript, angular, safari

I can successfully put stuff into the `localStorage` in the private mode of mobile Safari. And if I open my web app in 2 different tabs, they don't have access to the same `localStorage`. By that, I mean if I set a value in the 1st tab, my app in the 2nd tab can't see it. This might happen in other browsers' private mode too but I haven't got a chance to test them.

The same code works fine if it is not private mode. The value set by the 1st tab can be accessed by the 2nd tab.

Is there an alternate solution to `localStorage` or it is just impossible in the private mode?

Comment: did you get a solution to the problem. And did you get confirmation on this, that it is the default behaviour of safari in private mode, that local storage can not be shared across tabs

Answer (score 0):

You could [connect to a back-end server and store your data](https://www.derekshidler.com/inserting-form-data-into-mysql-using-php-and-ajax/) in a database, but **private mode is specifically meant to block cookies and forms of local storage, so you cannot reliably store your data across tabs in the frontend**. Users know this, and they don't expect accounts to stay logged in or anything of the like. That being said, if your function seems like something users would expect to still be able to use it across tabs, invest the time to check out [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp), [PHP insertion with MySQL](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-insert-query.php), and [PHP retrieval with MySQL](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp). If this data needs to be device-specific, you can grab the user's ip address with PHP using `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` and associate the data with their IP in your database, but be aware that IPs can change if the user changes networks.

Comment: You are indeed correct. My app issues each client a GUID. And the client needs the GUID to activate their account after registering. So when the client jumps from the activation link from their mail box, a 2nd tab will be launched without being able to get the same GUID and therefore fails the account activation. I was considering IPs but it’s gonna fundamentally change the account registration process.

Comment: You can send the GUID to the backend when they register and send it as a parameter in the verification link in the email. Then the verification page can grab it from the URL. It's better that way anyway because they might have registered on laptop and be activating on mobile.

Comment: Unless by "each client a GUID" you mean that you want to specifically forbid cross-device compatibility

Comment: That is the very case I don’t want my users to do. I want them to use the same device and the same browser to register and activate.

Comment: You could play around with crazy stuff like combining the cross-device method I mentioned earlier, but also send the screen size, devicePixelRatio, and other device-specific data along with the GUID that your activation page could compare against. Of course it's not bullet-proof, but it's something.

Comment: If this answer was helpful (though possibly disappointing), please mark it with an accepted checkmark and upvote. Thanks!