# Is local storage not shared between tabs on Safari and Firefox Private mode?

Tags: javascript, cookies, safari, local-storage

I am storing a boolean value in local storage and things were working fine, until i realized that safari private mode doesnt really shares that local storage across tabs. I am storing the users confirmation on my site, if they have accepted the cookie notification/banner on the website and based on this local storage value, i show it or hide it. But on safari private mode, that is being shown always on first load, since this local storage is not used across tabs.

So, for e.g. if i load my page in safari private mode, and store this value. Then open another tab, then this value wouldnt be read and i see my banner again.

```
localStorage.setItem('cookie_consent', true)
```

Codepen - https://codepen.io/yogesharora28/pen/KKzobNL

If we try the above codepen in private mode, we can see it always logs that its not stored.

I was looking for confirmation as to if this is official safari behaviour or not. Looked for similar questions here, just found this one - [localStorage is not shared across tabs in the private mode in mobile Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59587465/localstorage-is-not-shared-across-tabs-in-the-private-mode-in-mobile-safari), but has not been answered.

Comment: sessionStorage is scoped to a single tab.  localStorage is scoped to all tabs

Comment: @taplar so this behaviour varies across browsers. As Chrome, IE11 and Edge share the localstorage across tabs in private/incognito mode.

Comment: Yeah, localStorage is multi-tabbed.  I had it backwards originally.

Comment: @Taplar yeah, but in Safari/FF private mode ,it doesnt seem to work this way.

Comment: Some browsers may disable things, such as storage and service workers and cookies, when running in private mode.

Comment: As of July/2022 I can confirm that Firefox and Chrome (on mobile) will share localStorage between private tabs, but Safari (tested on iOS 11.0 and iOS 15.4) does NOT share localStorage between private tabs. Years ago, there was an interesting [debate/discussion](https://blog.whatwg.org/this-week-in-html-5-episode-30) about how private tabs should work and it's worth checking out (there's really no right answer, you simply have to test the browsers and design for their differences).